# MVC 4 using existing Authenication process in ASP.Net Webservice

Tags: web-services, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have spent a few hours today trying to get my head around the best way to do this.

I am new to MVC 4 and I am currently in the process of migrating a old .Net 3.5 Windows Forms application to MVC 4.

We currently log users in by passing their credentials to a ASP.Net SOAP Web Service and returning back an entity called User which contains a number of custom fields.

If the User Entity is not null and has an ID, we log the user in.

I understand there is a new membership provider as well as an AuthorizeAttributes class in MVC, but I am not sure if I can really utilize them.

Ideally I want to persist the login status across the application, so if the user logs out, or the session is timed out they need to be redirected back to the Login Form.

Should I just store the User entity in a Session and use some type of Global Filter or is there a better way to do this?